# How can I set proxy details in maven when I am using a wireless connection?

Tags: maven

How can I set the proxy port and host in settings.xml  in maven while I uses the net connection from my mobile using hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Maven basically doesn't care about network interfaces (Wireless or wired connection).
You just specify the proxy in terms of host/port and if its able to access it it will use it.

Pay attention however, since Maven tends to download a lot of stuff, you might quickly exceed the quota of data to download in the mobile connection... ;)

Comment: Where can I find the proxy host and port in my system while using net from mobile hotspot?

Comment: Basically proxy is a server through which you connect to the internet. Usually its set up by organization IT department or something, so you should ask them: where its accessible, how does it work network wise when you're on hotspot as you say. The point of my answer is that maven doesn't really takes care of connection type. its your responsibility to specify the proxy if you really need it...

Comment: Can I leave proxy settings empty? When i leave it empty in project it shows cannot read settings.xml.

Comment: How can I set settings.xml in this case??

Comment: By default maven definitions do not contain a proxy configuration... Check any basic maven example...